# Suggestions on best practices for organizing file in project

Tags: blazor

Below you can see the pages folder of a Blazor app I'm working on.  As you can see the files are getting kinda nuts.  Can anyone suggestion anything as to nesting files below the files they reference?

[image]

Is using folders a good option?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I personally like to order files by feature, or in a general 'components' folder if it's really generic. So something like:

[image]

Though the exact file arrangement will likely depend on a lot of factors including personal preference.

One thing I do personally recommend is nesting code behind under your .razor files (though again this is personal preferences). This can be done by ending the codebehind file with .razor.cs. So something like ContributorDetails.razor would result in the codebehind file ContributorDetails.razor.cs.

Example:

ContributorDetails.razor

```
<h2>
Your razor code here
</h2>
```

ContributorDetails.razor.cs

```
public partial class ContributorDetails
{
    The rest of your class here
}
```

Doing it like this makes it so your base class doesn't need to inherit from ComponentBase explicitly. It also keeps thing together in a clean way, but again I've also heard people prefer the method you're using with a base class seperate from the .razor file.

I would recommend placing each component in it's own folder if you don't use the nesting, because if you also add some scoped css it does become clutterd quite quickly.